# Gradle discards my source paths set with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have set up additional source path in my IntelliJ project:

[image]

As you see `src\attempts\java` was added.

Unfortunately, once I click Gradle refresh:

[image]

this information is discarded and I need to add it again.

How do I tell Gradle not to discard it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the gradle refersh button causes gradle to refresh the project. It has no idea of what you have done through intellij.

To get around this, you should add `src\attempts\java` to your sourcesets in gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/attempts/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about sourceSets here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: What are that nested names, `main` and `java`?

Comment: @Dims Those names are saying that you are adding these to the main java source sets. if you want to add extra locations to the test source set, you can add it under test/java. Answer updated with link to relevant docs.

Comment: @Dims, did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, main question is answered, yes, but comment still not. What if I have sources in `MyOwnLanguage`, can I just write this text instead of `java`?

Comment: @Dims, sorry, but I am not sure I understand. Are you talking about defining your own custom source sets? If so, then yes this is possible. All `main/java` means is that anything under the location in question is a valid place to store java source code.